# How to avoid to have many missed and pending cron jobs?

Tags: magento2, database, cron

This below is how my `cron_schedule` table looks like, how could I avoid having so many cron jobs **pending** or **missed**?

[image: Magento 2 Cronjobs missing or pending]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening for two possible reasons:

- Low server capacity by the number of cron jobs.
- Not ideal prioritization.

You can solve that by changing the time that Magento takes to schedule the next job, and increasing the **Missed if Not Run Within** time, in case it's an essential CRON job you can add it to a separate process, if it's not essential you can add many minutes to it.

[image: Magento 2 Cron Scheduled Tasks]

Don't forget to clean up your cache schedule by running these commands below.

```
n98-magerun2.phar db:query "DELETE from cron_schedule WHERE status='error' OR status='pending' OR status='missed'";
rm -rf var/cron/*
bin/magento cron:run
```

More details about the [Cron (Scheduled Tasks)](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/cron.html?) in the admin panel.